# ¿Cómo guardar cadenas de texto en un array con un bucle?

Tags: python, string, lista, regex

Contexto: Estoy utilizando pyPDF2 para extraer ciertos datos de un PDF, una parte del PDF aparecen nombres de personas, su numero de identificación y una fecha.
Por ejemplo:

```
Juan Pablo Hernandez Soza12345678-910-10-1887Carlos Alberto Suarez Soto87654321-K08-06-1998
```

Entonces quiero almacenar solo los nombres, para eso le quité los digitos, lo que da como resultado:

```
Juan Pablo Hernandez Soza---Carlos Alberto Suarez Soto-K--
```

Bueno aquí utilizo esta "logica" para que verifique cuando se topa con '---' o '-K--', pero no sé como ir almacenando cada vez que se tope con uno de ellos.

```
substring1 = '---'
substring2 = '-K--'

   if result.find(substring1) != -1 or result.find(substring2) != -1:
        #ALMACENE LA CADENA HASTA QUE ENCUENTRE EL SUBSTRING
   else:
        print('NotFound')
```

El objetivo del programa es que almacene solo los nombres de las personas en un array, y luego poder acceder a ellos.

Por ejemplo que la salida sea:

```
Print(nombre[0])
Salida: Juan Pablo Hernandez Soza
```

```
Print(nombre[1])
Salida: Carlos Alberto Suarez Soto
```

Comment: osea quieres que apenas aparezca un "-" no se considere la derecha del string?

Comment: @DannyTalent mm no, ya que eso cortaria a la segunda persona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una cadena muy larga con texto de la forma:

```
nombre nombre nombreXXXXnombre nombre nombreYYYY
```

donde `XXX` y `YYY` son números y letras.

Por ello, creo que la clave está en buscar cadenas largas de letras y espacios. Por ejemplo con `[a-zA-Z ]{2,}` buscamos todas aquellas que tengan un mínimo de 2 caracteres:

```
>>> s = "Juan Pablo Hernandez Soza12345678-910-10-1887Carlos Alberto Suarez Soto87654321-K08-06-1998"                                                     
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z ]{2,}', s)
['Juan Pablo Hernandez Soza', 'Carlos Alberto Suarez Soto']
```

Como ves, esto ya te da una lista.

Comment: Si, funciona a la perfección, gracias!